# Error: while connecting Google Cloud Storage using Java => java.net.UnknownHostException: oauth2.googleapis.com

Tags: java, oauth, google-cloud-storage, google-oauth

While connecting to Google Cloud Storage using Java libraries, We are getting below exception :

1. Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: oauth2.googleapis.com
2. Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error getting access token for service account: oauth2.googleapis.com

We have created the Google Cloud Storage service account, Project and downloaded JSON file also.

Below is the code snippet :

```
GoogleCredentials googleCredentails = 
            ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("D:\\Naresh\\Projects\\GoogleCloudStorage\\delta-trees-236311-ae7c1cfcda68.json"));

Storage googleStorageService = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(googleCredentails)
            .setProjectId("delta-trees-236311")
            .build().getService();

String googleBucketName = "ewf-ocr-poc";
File f = new File("D:\\Naresh\\Projects\\GoogleCloudStorage\\EWFDocumentThroughJava.txt");
byte[] readFileToByteArray = readFileToByteArray(f);
String fileName = f.getName();
InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);        
googleStorageService.create(BlobInfo.newBuilder(googleBucketName, fileName).build(),
            readFileToByteArray);
```

Comment: Could anybody please help us.

Comment: It seems you don't have working internet or your network is blocking to access `oauth2.googleapis.com`. Try to ping and check if the server is accessible from your system

Comment: This is the error i am getting : Ping request could not find host oauth2.googleapi.com. Please check the name and
 try again.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the internet pemission.

try: Android studio:  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` On Android Manifest

Xamarin:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

On Android Manifest

Comment: I am running a stand-alone java program. How can we add this configuration to stand alone ?

Comment: OP is not asking about android application specifically.

Comment: I dont understand you  https://stackoverflow.com/users/3295987/pratapi-hemant-patel

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to add your https proxy in the java app to make your connection to gcp host work. You can add is using below system properties:

```
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", yourProxyHost);
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", yourProxyPort);
```